# What is the most elegant way to create a list of boolean of 100 elements initialized at false

Tags: arrays, vb.net, linq

Obviously I can do

```
    Dim primeornot = New List(Of Boolean)
    For i = 1 To 100
        primeornot.Add(False)
    Next
```

Which is actually short enough and probably don't take much longer than proper version.

Is there a more proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ if you want a shorter version:

```
Dim primeornot = Enumerable.Repeat(False, 100).ToList()
```

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't want to call `ToList`, you can pass the IEnumerable result as an argument when declaring a new List: `Dim collection = New List(Of Boolean)(Enumerable.Repeat(False, 100))`

Comment: @David: But it doesn't make the code more readable, concise or efficient

Comment: I would disagree with not making the code more efficient. While I haven't dug into it, my intuition tells me that when calling `ToList`, it will have a performance hit because it will have to enumerate the collection.

Comment: @David: Yes, in the same way as in the `List(Of T)` constructor if you pass something that is not a collection. The lists internal array will have to be resized multiple timers(doubles). So it's the same as in OP's code, but he asked for a short and readable version. If you want the most efficient you need to use `Dim primeornot=New List(Of Boolean)(100) primeornot.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(False, 100))` which also uses a loop but does not need to resize it. However, this is micro-optimization imo

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot ways to create a collection, as a `List(Of T)` or anything else.
Depending on the use case:

Hard-code the size, when you know in advance how many items the collection contains:

```
Dim bList = New Boolean(99) {}.ToList()
```

Based on parameters, using the `List(Of T)` constructor:

```
Dim items = 100
Dim bList = New List(Of Boolean)(New Boolean(items - 1) {})

Dim times = 100 : Dim value = False
Dim bList = New List(Of Boolean)(Enumerable.Repeat(value, times))
```

When you have two values that define a range:

```
Dim range As (iFrom As Integer, iTo As Integer, bValue As Boolean) = (50, 100, False)
Dim bList = Enumerable.Range(range.iFrom, range.iTo).Select(Function(b) range.bValue).ToList()
```

When you pre-build a `Func(Of T, [NumberOfItems], ReturnType(Of T))`:

```
Dim myFunc = New Func(Of Boolean, Integer, IEnumerable(Of Boolean))
   (Function(b, i) Enumerable.Repeat(b, i))

' [...]
Dim bList = New List(Of Boolean)(myFunc(False, 100))
```

A generic method that returns an `IEnumerable(OF T)`:

```
Dim boolList = GetCollection(100, False).ToList()
Dim decimalList = GetCollection(100, 100D).ToList()

' [...]

Public Function GetCollection(Of T As {Structure})
    (howMany As Integer, baseValue As T) As IEnumerable(Of T)
    Return Enumerable.Repeat(baseValue, howMany)
End Function
```

Comment: This one is good. But I got to pick one right answer

Comment: Sure, it's your question, you pick whatever answer you want :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `System.Collectios.BitArray` instead:

`Dim bitArray As New System.Collections.BitArray(100)`

All 100 values will be initialized to `false` by default.

Answer (score 0):

I would say this look elegant

```
    Dim trueifnotprime = New List(Of Boolean)(100)
```

All the boolean element is automatically set to false isn't it?