# Why does this syntax where we declare an array and converting it to list work?

Tags: vb.net

I saw someone write this

```
    Dim trueifnotprime = New Boolean(99) {}.ToList
```

And it works. I do not understand why.

What is actually going on? What is New Boolean(99)? Am I creating a boolean array or am I calling boolean constructor with 99 parameter? Then what is the {} thingy? What kind of notation is this?

Comment: Do you mean in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66954693/7444103)? You could have asked.

Comment: You should consider to accept answers in your questions or at least give feedback

Comment: I did. Sorry. But yes someone uses that strange notation and I wonder how it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `New` refers to the constructor of the array.

`Boolean` is the Data Type

`(99)` is the size of the array. 99 being the index of the upper bound of the array.

`{}` could contain the values for the elements of the array. Since it is empty the array is initialized with the default value for Boolean, False.

`.ToList` converts the array to a List(Of T)

Comment: So the {} is the initialize and the bracket signify the array parameter () and not the method operator, which is also ().

Comment: Can I saw some link? We can add {} after array declaration to initialize an array?

Comment: Here is a link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/how-to-initialize-an-array-variable